# Django Runserver Never Starts

Tags: python, django

When I run the runserver command, the commandline stops at:

> from django.utils import importlib, six, dateparse

And doesn't go any further. The process never ends and it won't stop loading. What would cause it to freeze at that point?

Comment: Please check if importlib, six, dateparse are installed in your machine.

Comment: @MaJi Yup, they're all present. I've actually used the runserver command just a few hours ago. I added things to the app since (Views, Urls). The syntax is fine. Even if it weren't, runserver will usually fail and tell me where the erroneous syntax is. I'm really at a loss here. Also, when I push the changes to Heroku, the app runs just fine.

Comment: Is there anything else in traceback when you run server?

Comment: @MaJi Nothing else. This is it:  /home/ubuntu/virtualenvironments/myapp/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/allauth/utils.py:11: RemovedInDjango19Warning: django.utils.importlib will be removed in Django 1.9.
  from django.utils import importlib, six, dateparse

Comment: It's just a warning. Open browser and try accessing localhost. Might work.

Comment: @MaJi I tried that, sadly. I get an unable to connect error.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I had one or two:

```
django.setup()
```

lines sprinkled in some files. When I removed them, the server was able to run again.